# How to save an array of data to local storage in an AngularJS app?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm try to create angularJS app on iOS and I would like to save a data on checkbox into local storage.

Now I have array of information of checkbox

```
$scope.cuisineList = [
    { text: "Asian Cuisine", checked: true },
    { text: "Cafe", checked: true },
    { text: "Chinese Cuisine", checked: true },
    { text: "Dessert and Bekery", checked: true },
    { text: "Dim Sum", checked: false },
    { text: "Ice Cream", checked: false },
    { text: "Japanese Cuisine", checked: false },
    { text: "Kiwi Cuisine", checked: false },
    { text: "Korean Cruisine", checked: false },
    { text: "Thai Cuisine", checked: false },
    { text: "Vegeterian Cuisine", checked: false }
];
```

and my html5 (i use iconic framework)

```
<ion-checkbox ng-repeat="item in cuisineList"
                  ng-model="item.checked" 
                  ng-checked="item.checked"
                  ng-change="cuisineListChange()">
            {{ item.text }}
        </ion-checkbox>
```

when something change on checkbox, it will perform `cuisineListChange()` function which I would like to save `$scope.cuisineList` into.

please give me an example, how to use local storage to save checkbox.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As you can't store objects in the localStorage or sessionStorage, you will need to serialize them (so a string will be saved to localStorage, that needs to be parsed when getting it back).

To store, use:

```
localStorage.setItem('cuisineList', JSON.stringify($scope.cuisineList));
```

To get the data back from localStorage, use:

```
$scope.cuisineList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cuisineList'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a useful object:

```
var LocalStorageManager = {
    setValue: function(key, value) {
        window.localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
    },
    getValue: function(key) {
        try {
            return JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem(key));
        } catch (e) {

        }
    }
};
```

To save data:

```
LocalStorageManager.setValue("key",data);
```

To retrieve that data:

```
LocalStorageManager.getValue("key");
```